# I'm trying to decode json array to php but it's returning a blank page

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to decode json array to php array using `json_decode`, but it's displaying a blank page

Here's the json array

```
[["id":"2","name":"Sam Nju","photo":"1510074080885.jpg","qty":"10","price":"10000.00"],["id":"3","name":"Daniel","photo":"1510074047056.jpg","qty":"0","price":"40000.00"]]
```

Here's the code to decode json

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://localhost/example/index.php/destinations/json');

   $data = json_decode($json,true);
   $names = $data['result'];
   echo "<pre>";
   echo $names;

   print_r($names);
```

Thanks

Comment: Blank page typically means a 500 error. Have you checked your logs or turned on error_reporting to debug? There is nothing in your code sample that would point to an error that would cause a blank page. Also, have you tried `print_r($data)` to verify if there is a `result` key?

Comment: Blank page can also mean he gets `NULL` from the `json_decode()` if his JSON is in bad format and as far as I can see it is.

Comment: Hi @Ivan86, Pls could you tell me how it can be written, Thanks

Comment: Looks like data itself would be an array containing arrays. So you might need $data[0]['name']. Although the inner array is acting like an object so I don't know if it would ever work.

Comment: Is that URL valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For obtaining proper `JSON` using `json_decode()` and `json_encode()` follow these guidelines:

> **json_decode() :**
>
> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings.
>
> Returns the value encoded in json in appropriate PHP type. Values true, false and null are returned as TRUE, FALSE and NULL respectively. NULL is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit.
>
> The key and value must be enclosed in double quotes single quotes are not valid.

Your JSON:

```
[["id":"2","name":"Sam Nju","photo":"1510074080885.jpg","qty":"10","price":"10000.00"],["id":"3","name":"Daniel","photo":"1510074047056.jpg","qty":"0","price":"40000.00"]]
```

apears to be invalid. `Arrays` use `[]` while `objects` use `{}`.

This is an example of how a proper PHP array structure would look like prior to doing `json_encode()` (before sending):

```
// array structure in PHP to get proper JSON
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2 [name] => Sam Nju [photo] => 1510074080885.jpg [qty] => 10 [price] => 10000.00 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 3 [name] => Daniel [photo] => 1510074047056.jpg [qty] => 0 [price] => 40000.00 ) )
```

which was obtained using the following:

```
json_decode('[{"id":"2","name":"Sam Nju","photo":"1510074080885.jpg","qty":"10","price":"10000.00"},{"id":"3","name":"Daniel","photo":"1510074047056.jpg","qty":"0","price":"40000.00"}]', true)
```

which would mean doing this:

```
$myArray = array();
$firstPerson = array();              
$secondPerson = array();

$firstPerson['id'] = 2;
$firstPerson['name'] = "Sam Nju";
// ...

$secondPerson['id'] = 3;
$firstPerson['name'] = "Daniel";
// ...

array_push($myArray, $firstPerson);
array_push($myArray, $secondPerson);

// or $myArray[0] = $firstPerson; and $myArray[1] = $secondPerson;
```

While valid `JSON` would look like this:

```
{{"id":"2","name":"Sam Nju","photo":"1510074080885.jpg","qty":"10","price":"10000.00"},{"id":"3","name":"Daniel","photo":"1510074047056.jpg","qty":"0","price":"40000.00"}}
```

If you are getting the data from a database you might want to use something like this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ....  // database query, $con is connection variable  

$myArray = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $tempArray = array();
    $tempArray['id'] = $row[0];
    $tempArray['name'] = $row[1];
    $tempArray['photo'] = $row[2];
    // ...

    array_push($myArray, $tempArray);
}

// use print_r($myArray); to test it out.
```

Comment: Thanks, please how will I print the first array

Comment: @N.francis I edited to add an example of how to make an array from data received from a  database query.  (At the bottom)

Comment: I'm getting the data from url,Couldn't figure how to display the first array

Comment: Can you please show code of the PHP file that is generating the JSON ? That would make it much easier to pinpoint the current problem

Comment: @N.francis let me know when you update to show the PHP file that is generating the array (URL). It's likely the problem lies there.

Comment: @N.francis Glad to hear that :) Peace

Answer (score 2):

Although your code looks correct, your JSON data is invalid. Objects are enclosed by `{}`, not `[]`. Replace the JSON with this, and it should work.

```
[
  {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Sam Nju",
        "photo": "1510074080885.jpg",
        "qty": "10",
        "price": "10000.00"
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Daniel",
        "photo": "1510074047056.jpg",
        "qty": "0",
        "price": "40000.00"
    }
]
```

Comment: I still go a blank page

Comment: Please provide a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); your code should be correct, provided the JSON is in a proper format.

Answer (score 1):

Also above answer already mentioned it:
Your JSON is invalid. You can check this e.g. with an JSON linter like https://jsonlint.com/

Plus, you're referencing names with `$names = $data['result'];`. However, in your provided JSON there is no array (or better object), with key "result".

You may look up your PHP's error log file to understand where the problem lies.